# how to prove the eigenvalues of tridiagonal matrix

Tags: numerical-methods

Assume the tridiagonal matrix $T$ in this form:
$$
T = \begin{bmatrix}
a       & c        &              &              & \\
b       & a        & c            &              & \\
        & b        & a            & \ddots       & \\
        &          & b            & a            & \\
        &          &              & b            & \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
we must show the eagen valus have form 
 $$ a+2\sqrt{bc}\, \cos(k \pi/{(n+1)})  $$

Comment: That is clearly not true. For example, if all the $\gamma_i$ are zero, the eigenvalues are $\alpha_i$ for $i=1,\ldots,n$.

Comment: Do we know anything about $\alpha_i$, $\beta_i$, and $\gamma_i$?

Comment: yes.$a=q$h^2$-1$  and  $b =$1-p*h/{2}$ and  $c =$1+p*h/{2}$ such that$ q<=0$

Comment: Please don't ask [the same question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/955168/how-to-prove-the-eigenvalues-of-tridiagonal-matrix) twice. I am voting to close this one, as the other (newer) one has some answers.