# Find the determinant $Δ_n$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

> Find the determinant $\Delta_n$

### $A_n = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 &\dots &\dots&0\\ -1 & 0 &1 & 0&&\vdots\\ 0&-1 & 0 &1 &\ddots&\vdots\\ \vdots& & & &\ddots&0\\ \vdots& & \ddots &\ddots &\ddots&1\\ 0 & \dots & \dots &0&-1&0 \end{bmatrix} \in M_n(\mathbb{K})$

After doing some tests I conclude $\Delta_n$ is $0$ if  $n$ is odd and $1$ if $n$ is even. How can I prove it formally? Any hint?

Comment: Do the [Laplace expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_expansion) along the first row and column to get $\Delta_n=\Delta_{n-2}$. Then $\Delta_1$ and $\Delta_2$ are obvious.

Comment: An alternate approach for the case of odd $n$: $A$ is skew-symmetric.  So, if $n$ is odd, we have
$$
\det(A) = \det(A^T) = \det(-A) = (-1)^n \det(A) = -\det(A)
$$
That is, we have $\det(A) = -\det(A)$ which means that $\det(A) = 0$.

Comment: You could also use [more general results](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/955168/how-to-find-the-eigenvalues-of-tridiagonal-toeplitz-matrix) about tridiagonal Toeplitz matrices

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**:

Expanding by the last row, prove that
$$\Delta_n=\begin{vmatrix}0&1&0&\dots&0&0&0 \\ -1&0&1&\dots&0&0&0 \\  0&-1& 0 & \cdots&0&0&0\\
\vdots&&& \vdots &&&\vdots \\0&0&0&\cdots&0&1&0 \\0&0&0&\dots&-1&0&0 \\0&0&0&\dots&0&-1&1\end{vmatrix}=\Delta_{n-2} \;\text{ (expanding by the last column)}$$