# Solving Linear Algebra Problem from Berkeley Qual Spring 1990 Using Calculus

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am looking for a calculus solution of the following problem:

**Problem.** (Berkeley Qual Spring 1990):

> Let $n$ br a positive integer, and let $A_n:= (a_{ij}) \in
> M_n(\mathbb{R})$ be a matrix given by $a_{ii} =2,\ a_{i,i+1} = -1,\
> a_{ij} = 0$ otherwise. For instance,
>
> $A_4 = \begin{pmatrix} 2  & -1 & 0 & 0\\  -1 & 2 & -1 &0 \\  0 & -1 & 2 & -1\\  0 & 0 & -1 & 2 \end{pmatrix} $
>
> Prove that every eigenvalue of $A$ is a positive real number.

Here is the solution I am trying to complete.

> We proceed by induction on $n$. Let $p_n(t) := \det(A_n-t Id)$, i.e. the characteristic
> polynomial of $A_n$. This satisfies the recursive rule $p_{n+2}(t) =(2-t)p_{n+1}(t) - p_n(t)$. It suffices to show that $p_n>0$ for all
> $t<0$.
>
> The base case is easy. For the induction step, it is sufficient to
> prove the bound $|p_n(t)| \le (2-t)p_{n+1}(t)$ for $t<0$. **How do can
> we prove this bound**?

It's clear from $\deg p_n(t) = n$ that for $t \to - \infty$, the bound is satisfied, but this is not enough.

Note: my question is *not* a solution to the Problem above (see Note 2), but rather a solution using *my* particular approach (or a similar approach doing calculus on characteristic polynomials).

Note 2: I already know two solutions; one is to prove $A_n$ is positive definite, and another is to prove some bounds for entries of eigenvectors. See Problem 7.5.27 in *Berkeley Problems in Mathematics*. The point of my question is to solve the Problem in as many was as possible.

Comment: There are many ways to prove that $A_n$ is positive definite. Here are four of them. **(1)** $A$ is positive definite because $A=(I-N)(I-N)^T+E_{nn}$, where $N$ is the upper triangular nilpotent Jordan block of size $n$. **(2)** Let $d_n=\det(A_n)$. Then $d_n=2d_{n-1}-d_{n-2}$. Hence $d_n-d_{n-1}=d_{n-1}-d_{n-2}=\cdots=d_2-d_1=3-2=1$ and $d_n=n+1>0$. Now apply Sylvester's criterion. **(3)** Using $A_n=e_1e_1^T+\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}(e_i-e_{i+1})(e_i-e_{i+1}^T)+e_ne_n^T$, prove that $x^TAx=0$ only if $x=0$...

Comment: ... **(4)** Determine the eigenvalues of $A_n$ directly. See e.g. the many answers to the question [How to find the eigenvalues of tridiagonal Toeplitz matrix?
](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/955168) All these four approaches are probably easier than yours.

Comment: *easiest approach:* Apply Gerschgoin Discs: it is immediate that all eigenvalues are real non-negative and Tausky's refinement tells you the matrix is non-singular thus it is PD. *Another one:* consider $\big(-\frac{1}{2}A +I\big)$ -- this is a transition matrix for a connected transient markov chain and thus all eigenvalues have modulus $\lt 1$ (or use Perron Frobenius theory) -- now negate and add $I$ to see that  $\frac{1}{2}A$ has all eigenvalues with positive real part -- and since symmetric they are entirely real positive eigenvalues.

Comment: **"It suffices to show that $p_n>0$ for all  $t<0$."** Impossible.   Suppose $n$ is odd.  Then $p_n$ is a real monic polynomial with of odd degree $n$.  Hence $p_n\big(-\vert t\vert\big) \lt 0$ for $\vert t\vert$ large enough.

Comment: @user8675309 I just made a correction. With the definition of characteristic polynomial as $p_n(t) := \det(A_n - t Id)$, then we get leading order term $-t^n$ when $n$ odd, and so, $p_n(- |t|)\to \infty$ for $|t|$ large.

Answer (score 4):

$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
1 & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
2 & 0 \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
2 &  - 1 \\ 
 - 1 & 2 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 &  -  \frac{ 2 }{ 3 }  & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
2 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  \frac{ 4 }{ 3 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 2 }{ 3 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
2 &  - 1 & 0 \\ 
 - 1 & 2 &  - 1 \\ 
0 &  - 1 & 2 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  -  \frac{ 2 }{ 3 }  & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  -  \frac{ 3 }{ 4 }  & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }  & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  \frac{ 4 }{ 3 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 &  \frac{ 5 }{ 4 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 2 }{ 3 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 3 }{ 4 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
2 &  - 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 - 1 & 2 &  - 1 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 1 & 2 &  - 1 \\ 
0 & 0 &  - 1 & 2 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  -  \frac{ 2 }{ 3 }  & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  -  \frac{ 3 }{ 4 }  & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 &  -  \frac{ 4 }{ 5 }  & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrr} 
2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }  & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  \frac{ 4 }{ 3 }  & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 &  \frac{ 5 }{ 4 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  \frac{ 6 }{ 5 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 2 }{ 3 }  & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 3 }{ 4 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 4 }{ 5 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrr} 
2 &  - 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 - 1 & 2 &  - 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 1 & 2 &  - 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  - 1 & 2 &  - 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 &  - 1 & 2 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_law_of_inertia#Statement_in_terms_of_eigenvalues

Comment: From the question: "Note: my question is not a solution to the Problem above (see Note 2), but rather a solution using my particular approach (or a similar approach doing calculus on characteristic polynomials)."

Comment: @JohnHughes I know. Indeed, just yesterday I got about four downvotes on a picture of an ellipse that I did by hand; eventually I deleted it. I still think there is room for answering the question the OP should have asked.

Comment: Fair enough. I also suspected that OP might need to "strengthen the induction" to make it work, and that turns out to be true (see @user8675309's comment), so OP was asking for something impossible anyhow.

Comment: @JohnHughes  thank you.

Answer (score 1):

We will find a formula for the eigenvalues of $n \times n$ matrix

$A = \begin{pmatrix}2 & -1 & 0 & \cdots &  0 \\-1 & 2 & -1 & \ddots & \vdots\\  0 & -1 & \ddots &  \ddots & 0\\ \vdots & \cdots & \ddots & 2 & -1 \\ 0 & \cdots & 0 & -1 & 2  \end{pmatrix}$

Solution:

Let $x = \begin{pmatrix}x_{1} \\ x_{2} \\ \vdots \\ x_{n-1} \\ x_{n} \end{pmatrix} $

The components in $(A - \lambda I)x = 0$ are $-x_{k-1} + (2-\lambda)x_{k} - x_{k+1} =0, k = 1, 2, \cdots, n$ with $x_{0} = x_{n+1} = 0$.

Treating that recurrence relation like a differential equation, we seek a solution of the form $x_{k} = cr^{k}$ and on plugging in we get:

$r^{2} - \gamma r + 1 = 0$, where $\gamma = 2 - \lambda$.

Note that we must have two distinct solutions for this quadratic equation since otherwise we will get the solutions $x_{k} = \alpha \rho^{k} + \beta k \rho^{k}$ which becomes zero for all $k$ since $x_{0} = 0$ and $x_{n + 1} = 0$ and since we are seeking an eigenvector this would not be allowed. Hence, we must have two distinct roots $r_{1}, r_{2}$ and the solutions are given by $x_{k} = \alpha r_{1}^{k} + \beta r_{2}^{k}$. Note that $x_{0} = 0 \implies \alpha = -\beta$ and this together with $x_{n + 1} = 0 \implies r_{2}^{n+1} - r_{1}^{n + 1} = 0 \implies$ that $\frac{r_{1}}{r_{2}}$ is a root of unity. Hence $r_{1} = r_{2} e^{2\frac{i \pi j} {n + 1}}$

Factoring and comparing the coefficients:

$r^{2} - \gamma r + 1 = (r -  r_{1}) (r- r_{2}) = r^{2} - (r_{1} + r_{2}) r + r_{1}r_{2} \implies r_{1}r_{2} = 1, r_{1} + r_{2} = \gamma$.

We have $r_{1} = e^{\frac{i \pi j} {n + 1}}$, $r_{2} = e^{-\frac{i \pi j} {n + 1}}$

Hence, the eigenvalues of $A$ are $\lambda_{j} = 2- \gamma_{j}  = 2- 2\cos \frac{j \pi}{n + 1} $ for $j = 1, 2, \cdots, n$

It follows that $\lambda_{j} > 0$.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I follow why working with a recurrence and applying triangle inequality is 'calculus'.  The below is a proof that  comes down to (1.) using the recurrence and (2.) applying Cauchy Interlacing.

*The recurrence*
$p_{n+2}(t) =(2-t)p_{n+1}(t) - p_n(t)$
where $p_n(t) := (-1)^n\cdot \det\big(tI_n - A_n\big)= \det\big(A_n-tI_n \big)$
i.e. it is $(-1)^n$ times the characteristic polynomial.

By induction hypothesis we have  $A_n$ having all positive eigenvalues, that is
$p_n(t)= \big(\lambda_1^{(n)}-t\big)\big(\lambda_2^{(n)}-t\big)...\big(\lambda_n^{(n)}-t\big)$
with each $\lambda_k^{(n)}\gt 0$

We want to prove this implies $\lambda_k^{(n+1)}\gt 0$ for $k\in \{1,2,...,n,n+1\}$

**Now suppose** $p_{n+1}(t^*) =0$ for some $t^*\in(-\infty, 0]$ and apply the recurrence twice.
$p_{n+2}(t^*) =(2-t^*)p_{n+1}(t^*) - p_n(t^*) = 0 - p_n(t^*) \lt 0$
$p_{n+3}(t^*) =(2-t^*)p_{n+2}(t^*) - p_{n+1}(t^*) = (2-t^*)p_{n+2}(t^*)-0 \lt 0$

The eigenvalues in each of these polynomials **interlace**
$0=p_{n+1}(t^*)= \Big(\big(\lambda_1^{(n+1)}-t^*\big)...\big(\lambda_n^{(n+1)}-t^*\big)\Big)\cdot \big(\lambda_{n+1}^{(n+1)}-t^*\big)$
Interlacing of eigenvalues of $A_{n}$ and $A_{n+1}$ tells us the first $n$ terms in the above are necessarily positive and the last term is zero.

$p_{n+3}(t^*)= \Big(\big(\lambda_1^{(n+3)}-t^*\big)...\big(\lambda_n^{(n+3)}-t^*\big)\big(\lambda_{n+1}^{(n+3)}-t^*\big)\Big)\cdot\Big(\big(\lambda_{n+2}^{(n+3)}-t^*\big)\big(\lambda_{n+3}^{(n+3)}-t^*\big)\Big)$
Since $t^*$ is not a root for $p_{n+3}$ but the eigenvalues of $A_{n+3}$ interlace with those of $A_{n+1}$ we see the first $n+1$ terms are all positive and the last 2 terms are negative giving us
$0\gt p_{n+3}(t^*)= \Big(\gt 0 \Big)\cdot \Big(\gt 0\Big)\gt 0$
which is a contradiction.

Thus $p_{n+1}(t^*) \neq 0$ for any $t^*\in(-\infty, 0]$  and the positivity of all eigenvalues follows.

**addendum**
to see the interlacing of e.g. eigenvalues of e.g. the $n$ and $n+1$ dim case, consider with standard basis vectors $\mathbf e_k\in \mathbb R^{n+1}$
$B := \bigg[\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c}
\mathbf e_1 & \mathbf e_2 &\cdots  &\mathbf e_n
\end{array}\bigg]$
$B^TB = I_n$ and
$B^T\big(A_{n+1}\big)B = A_n$