# Trig properties to factor out $4 \sin^2(n \pi / (2N)$

Tags: linear-algebra, trigonometry

I have a vector that looks like

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
2\sin(n\pi/N) - \sin(2n\pi/N) \\
- \sin(n\pi/N) + 2\sin(2n\pi/N) - \sin(3n\pi/N) \\
- \sin(2n\pi/N) + 2\sin(3n\pi/N) - \sin(4n\pi/N) \\
- \sin(3n\pi/N) + 2\sin(4n\pi/N) - \sin(5n\pi/N) \\
\vdots \\
- \sin((N-2)n\pi/N) + 2\sin((N-1)n\pi/N)
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Somehow I'm supposed to pull out $4 \sin^2(n \pi / (2N)$ from the vector and get

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\sin(n\pi/N) \\
\sin(2n\pi/N) \\
\sin(3n\pi/N) \\
\vdots \\
\sin((N-1)n\pi/N) \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

But it's not obvious to me how to do this...

Comment: (i) simplify the notation by writing $\theta:=n\pi/2N$ (ii) split the $2\sin$ term as $\sin+sin$ and then use addition formula on first two terms, second two terms, then use addition formula.

Comment: Are you sure the last entry of your first vector is correct ?

Comment: @JeanMarie should be fixed now

Comment: @ancientmathematician do you think you could hint one more time about which addition formula I should be looking at? I'm looking [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/TrigonometricAdditionFormulas.html)

Comment: See the edit I just added at the bottom of my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an answer that attempts to show the "great picture" behind your (in fact classical) question ; the corresponding computations have already been done and are not necessarily to be re-invented. Nevertheless, see the Edit at the bottom of this answer giving a direct approach.

Let $\theta:=n\pi/N$,
$$
V:=\begin{bmatrix}
\sin(\theta) \\
\sin(2\theta) \\
\sin(3\theta) \\
\vdots \\
\sin((N-1)\theta)
\end{bmatrix}$$

and $$
M:=\begin{bmatrix}
2&-1&0&0&\cdots &0&0&0\\
-1&2&-1&0&\cdots &0&0&0\\
0&-1&2&-1&\cdots &0&0&0\\
&&\ddots&\ddots&\ddots&&& \\
0&0&0&0&\cdots &-1&2&-1\\
0&0&0&0&\cdots &0&-1&2\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

Your issue means that you have to prove that

$$MV=\lambda V \ \ \text{with} \ \ \lambda:=(2\sin \theta/2)^2$$

It is an eigenvalue-eigenvector classical problem (see references below).

**References :**

1. It can be viewed as a consequence of the result given (and established) in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/955168) with $a=2, b=c=-1$ giving eigenvalues (taking into account that their matrix is an $n \times n$ matrix whereas our matrix $M$ is $(N-1) \times (N-1)$:

$$\lambda_k=a+2\sqrt{bc}\cos k\frac{\pi}{N}=2(1+\cos k\frac{\pi}{N})=2 \times 2 \cos^2(k\frac{\pi}{2N})\tag{1}$$

Take now $k=N-1$ and you will find the result you are looking for:

$$\lambda_{n-1}=4 \sin^2 \frac{\pi}{2N}$$

(the fact one finds a $\cos^2$ in (1) instead of a $\sin^2$ isn't important : $\sin$ and $\cos$ exchange their values when $k$ varies from $1$ to $n-1$).

2. Alternatively, see "Neumann case" with $k=1$ (smallest eigenvalue) at the bottom of [this Wikipedia reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors_of_the_second_derivative). This is because matrix $M$ can be considered as a discrete form of the opposite of the second derivative, which, not surprizingly, has a discretized version of the sine function (vector $V$) as an eigenvector.

**Edit: Hint for a direct solution:**

For the general case:

$-\sin (k-1)a+2 \sin ka-\sin (k+1)a$

$=2\ sin ka -(\sin (k-1)a)+2\sin (k+1)a)$

$=2\sin ka - 2 \sin \frac{(k-1)a+(k+1)a}{2}\cos \frac{(k-1)a-(k+1)a}{2}$

$=2 \sin ka-2 \sin ka \cos a = 2 \sin ka (1-\cos a)$

$=2 \sin ka \ \ 2 \sin^2 \frac{a}{2}$

knowing that you have to treat in a separate way the first and last term.