# Eigenvalues of tridiagonal Toeplitz matrix with diagonals $1$, $0$, and $-1$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, tridiagonal-matrices, toeplitz-matrices

Consider a matrix $A \in M_n(\mathbb{R})$ with entries denoted by $A=[a_{ij}]$. When $i=j+1$, $a_{ij}=1$, and when $i=j-1$, $a_{ij}=-1$, with all other entries being zero. Determine the eigenvalues of $A$.

To analyze the structure of $A$, consider the following representation for $n \times n$:

$$A = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & -1 & 0 & \dots & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & -1 & \dots & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & \dots & 0 & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 & -1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$

Eigenvalues were computed for small values of $n$ with the following outcomes:

- For $n=1$, the eigenvalues are $\{0\}$.
- For $n=2$, the eigenvalues are $\{i, -i\}$.
- For $n=3$, the eigenvalues are $\{i\sqrt{2}, -i\sqrt{2}, 0\}$.

However, finding a general expression for the eigenvalues of $A$ remains elusive. Assistance in solving this general case is highly appreciated.

Comment: I don´t know if this helps at all, but the sum of eigenvalues seems to be $0$. Moreover, if $\lambda$ is an eigenvale, $-\lambda$ seems to be either.

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/955168/339790)

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/toeplitz-matrices+tridiagonal-matrices+eigenvalues-eigenvectors)